# create redmine plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, redmine-plugins

I am creating a Redmine plug in for message system. For that I have created a model with name "communication.rb". here I want to create the Activerecord relationship between Communication model and User model(here User model already existing).

in user.rb

```
has_many :communications
```

in communication.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

How could I create relationship with existing model while creating plug in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add somewhere in you plugin:

```
User.class_eval do
  has_many :communications
end
```

Comment: please refer this gist(i have added the sample code and error message) https://gist.github.com/2427992

Comment: Are you sure that this message from you example has an user? From my perspective it looks like inconsistency in your db - message#user_id is NULL

Comment: Yeah i am sure this message has an USer

Comment: Actually it is works fine in controller but not in view. Please refer this gist https://gist.github.com/2428172